# Saving One To Many Relationship in Core Data, but after closing simulator only one item in the relationship. Fault in Console Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3, fault

I am loading a one to many relationship (and a bunch of other test data on initial load of my app into Core Data)
Side is an Entity with a one to many relationship of Frames:

```
let sideA = addNewSideToNSManagedObjectContext(orderInFlashcard: 0.0, frames: [frontFrame,backFrame], cardType: newCardType)
        let sideB = addNewSideToNSManagedObjectContext(orderInFlashcard: 1.0, frames: [backFrame,frontFrame], cardType: newCardType)
//context is saved after code above
```

After the initial data is load, I present a tableViewController where I click through a row to present the loaded data (basically I show a flashcard's side1.frames and then flashcard's side2.frames)
When I do this after the initial data load everything works and displays properly, side1.frames has 2 items and side2.frames has 2 items and they all display properly.

THE PROBLEM: When I close the simulator and rerun it (after the first run, data is already there and not loaded again), When i click through to display a flashcard, side1.frames has 2 items BUT side2.frames is EMTPY and I get a blank display. I'm really stumped at what the problem is because all the other data is persisted.

THE DATA with the problem is being accessed based on the current flashcard i'm displaying like so:

```
flashcard.cardType.sides
each side.frame (for subviews)
```

When I present the sides/frames, here is the code that retrieves the data for display:

```
func setupFramesForSides(){

        //var framesForSides:[[Frame]] = [[Frame]]() //property //goal to get array order by side.orderInFlashcard of arrays of frames for each side ordered by order in each side
        var sides:[Side] = (flashcard!.cardType!.sides!.allObjects as! [Side])
        sides.sort(by:{$0.orderInFlashcard<$1.orderInFlashcard}) //sides sorted by orderInFlashcard
        currentSideIndex = 0
        print("sides count:\(sides.count)")
        for s in 0..<sides.count{
            print("side:\(sides[s].orderInFlashcard)")
        }
        for sideIndex in 0..<sides.count{
            let side:Side = sides[sideIndex]
            print("currentSideIndex: \(sideIndex)")
            print("currentSide: \(side)")
            //create sorted array of frames for the side
            let frames:[Frame] = side.frames!.allObjects as! [Frame]
            print("framesAvailable:\(frames)")
            print("framesAvailable.count:\(frames.count)")
            //frames.sort(by:{$0<$1})
            var frameOrdersInSide:[Int:Frame] = [Int:Frame]()
            print("PREPARING NEW SIDE'S FRAMES")
            for sideFrame in frames{
                for orderInSide in sideFrame.orderInSides!.allObjects as! [FrameOrderInSide]{
                    if orderInSide.side == side {
                        print("FOUND MATCHING SIDE IN FRAME.ORDERINSIDES")
                        print("orderInSide:\(orderInSide.index)")
                        print("sideFrame:\(sideFrame)")
                        frameOrdersInSide[Int(orderInSide.index)] = sideFrame //index for frame in this side should never match another frame's index
                    }
                }
            }
            print("frameOrdersInSide:\(frameOrdersInSide)")
            print("frameOrdersInSide.count:\(frameOrdersInSide.count)")
            var sortedFramesInSide:[Frame] = [Frame]()
            for frameIndexInSide in 0..<(frameOrdersInSide.keys.sorted(by:{$0<$1})).count{
                sortedFramesInSide.append(frameOrdersInSide[frameIndexInSide]!) //array of Frames in order of the index in the side
            }
            framesForSides.append(sortedFramesInSide)
        }
```

Here are the console results from display from the initial load of the data without closing the simulator:

```
sides count:2
side:0.0
side:1.0
currentSideIndex: 0
currentSide: <FlashTags.Side: 0x6000000898d0> (entity: Side; id: 0xd000000000040010 <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/Side/p1> ; data: {
    frames =     (
        "0xd00000000004000a <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/Frame/p1>",
        "0xd00000000008000a <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/Frame/p2>"
    );
    orderInFlashcard = 0;
})
framesAvailable:[<FlashTags.Frame: 0x600000089740> (entity: Frame; id: 0xd00000000004000a <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/Frame/p1> ; data: {
    html = "{{kanjiImage}}";
    name = back;
    orderInSides =     (
        "0xd00000000008000c <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/FrameOrderInSide/p2>",
        "0xd00000000004000c <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/FrameOrderInSide/p1>"
    );
}), <FlashTags.Frame: 0x600000089510> (entity: Frame; id: 0xd00000000008000a <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/Frame/p2> ; data: {
    html = "{{englishKeyword}}";
    name = front;
    orderInSides =     (
        "0xd00000000010000c <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/FrameOrderInSide/p4>",
        "0xd0000000000c000c <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/FrameOrderInSide/p3>"
    );
})]
framesAvailable.count:2
PREPARING NEW SIDE'S FRAMES
FOUND MATCHING SIDE IN FRAME.ORDERINSIDES
orderInSide:1.0
sideFrame:<FlashTags.Frame: 0x600000089740> (entity: Frame; id: 0xd00000000004000a <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/Frame/p1> ; data: {
    html = "{{kanjiImage}}";
    name = back;
    orderInSides =     (
        "0xd00000000008000c <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/FrameOrderInSide/p2>",
        "0xd00000000004000c <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/FrameOrderInSide/p1>"
    );
})
FOUND MATCHING SIDE IN FRAME.ORDERINSIDES
orderInSide:0.0
sideFrame:<FlashTags.Frame: 0x600000089510> (entity: Frame; id: 0xd00000000008000a <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/Frame/p2> ; data: {
    html = "{{englishKeyword}}";
    name = front;
    orderInSides =     (
        "0xd00000000010000c <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/FrameOrderInSide/p4>",
        "0xd0000000000c000c <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/FrameOrderInSide/p3>"
    );
})
frameOrdersInSide:[0: <FlashTags.Frame: 0x600000089510> (entity: Frame; id: 0xd00000000008000a <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/Frame/p2> ; data: {
    html = "{{englishKeyword}}";
    name = front;
    orderInSides =     (
        "0xd00000000010000c <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/FrameOrderInSide/p4>",
        "0xd0000000000c000c <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/FrameOrderInSide/p3>"
    );
}), 1: <FlashTags.Frame: 0x600000089740> (entity: Frame; id: 0xd00000000004000a <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/Frame/p1> ; data: {
    html = "{{kanjiImage}}";
    name = back;
    orderInSides =     (
        "0xd00000000008000c <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/FrameOrderInSide/p2>",
        "0xd00000000004000c <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/FrameOrderInSide/p1>"
    );
})]
frameOrdersInSide.count:2
currentSideIndex: 1
currentSide: <FlashTags.Side: 0x61800008a7d0> (entity: Side; id: 0xd000000000080010 <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/Side/p2> ; data: {
    frames =     (
        "0xd00000000004000a <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/Frame/p1>",
        "0xd00000000008000a <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/Frame/p2>"
    );
    orderInFlashcard = 1;
})
framesAvailable:[<FlashTags.Frame: 0x600000089740> (entity: Frame; id: 0xd00000000004000a <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/Frame/p1> ; data: {
    html = "{{kanjiImage}}";
    name = back;
    orderInSides =     (
        "0xd00000000008000c <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/FrameOrderInSide/p2>",
        "0xd00000000004000c <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/FrameOrderInSide/p1>"
    );
}), <FlashTags.Frame: 0x600000089510> (entity: Frame; id: 0xd00000000008000a <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/Frame/p2> ; data: {
    html = "{{englishKeyword}}";
    name = front;
    orderInSides =     (
        "0xd00000000010000c <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/FrameOrderInSide/p4>",
        "0xd0000000000c000c <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/FrameOrderInSide/p3>"
    );
})]
framesAvailable.count:2
PREPARING NEW SIDE'S FRAMES
FOUND MATCHING SIDE IN FRAME.ORDERINSIDES
orderInSide:0.0
sideFrame:<FlashTags.Frame: 0x600000089740> (entity: Frame; id: 0xd00000000004000a <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/Frame/p1> ; data: {
    html = "{{kanjiImage}}";
    name = back;
    orderInSides =     (
        "0xd00000000008000c <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/FrameOrderInSide/p2>",
        "0xd00000000004000c <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/FrameOrderInSide/p1>"
    );
})
FOUND MATCHING SIDE IN FRAME.ORDERINSIDES
orderInSide:1.0
sideFrame:<FlashTags.Frame: 0x600000089510> (entity: Frame; id: 0xd00000000008000a <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/Frame/p2> ; data: {
    html = "{{englishKeyword}}";
    name = front;
    orderInSides =     (
        "0xd00000000010000c <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/FrameOrderInSide/p4>",
        "0xd0000000000c000c <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/FrameOrderInSide/p3>"
    );
})
frameOrdersInSide:[0: <FlashTags.Frame: 0x600000089740> (entity: Frame; id: 0xd00000000004000a <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/Frame/p1> ; data: {
    html = "{{kanjiImage}}";
    name = back;
    orderInSides =     (
        "0xd00000000008000c <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/FrameOrderInSide/p2>",
        "0xd00000000004000c <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/FrameOrderInSide/p1>"
    );
}), 1: <FlashTags.Frame: 0x600000089510> (entity: Frame; id: 0xd00000000008000a <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/Frame/p2> ; data: {
    html = "{{englishKeyword}}";
    name = front;
    orderInSides =     (
        "0xd00000000010000c <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/FrameOrderInSide/p4>",
        "0xd0000000000c000c <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/FrameOrderInSide/p3>"
    );
})]
frameOrdersInSide.count:2
```

After Closing the simulator, this is the issue as seen in the console:

```
sides count:2
side:0.0
side:1.0
currentSideIndex: 0
currentSide: <FlashTags.Side: 0x600000289420> (entity: Side; id: 0xd00000000004000e <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/Side/p1> ; data: {
    frames = "<relationship fault: 0x600000028940 'frames'>";
    orderInFlashcard = 0;
})
framesAvailable:[<FlashTags.Frame: 0x600000286810> (entity: Frame; id: 0xd000000000040010 <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/Frame/p1> ; data: <fault>), <FlashTags.Frame: 0x600000286bd0> (entity: Frame; id: 0xd000000000080010 <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/Frame/p2> ; data: <fault>)]
framesAvailable.count:2
PREPARING NEW SIDE'S FRAMES
FOUND MATCHING SIDE IN FRAME.ORDERINSIDES
orderInSide:1.0
sideFrame:<FlashTags.Frame: 0x600000286810> (entity: Frame; id: 0xd000000000040010 <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/Frame/p1> ; data: {
    html = "{{kanjiImage}}";
    name = back;
    orderInSides =     (
        "0xd000000000080012 <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/FrameOrderInSide/p2>",
        "0xd000000000040012 <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/FrameOrderInSide/p1>"
    );
})
FOUND MATCHING SIDE IN FRAME.ORDERINSIDES
orderInSide:0.0
sideFrame:<FlashTags.Frame: 0x600000286bd0> (entity: Frame; id: 0xd000000000080010 <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/Frame/p2> ; data: {
    html = "{{englishKeyword}}";
    name = front;
    orderInSides =     (
        "0xd0000000000c0012 <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/FrameOrderInSide/p3>",
        "0xd000000000100012 <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/FrameOrderInSide/p4>"
    );
})
frameOrdersInSide:[0: <FlashTags.Frame: 0x600000286bd0> (entity: Frame; id: 0xd000000000080010 <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/Frame/p2> ; data: {
    html = "{{englishKeyword}}";
    name = front;
    orderInSides =     (
        "0xd0000000000c0012 <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/FrameOrderInSide/p3>",
        "0xd000000000100012 <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/FrameOrderInSide/p4>"
    );
}), 1: <FlashTags.Frame: 0x600000286810> (entity: Frame; id: 0xd000000000040010 <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/Frame/p1> ; data: {
    html = "{{kanjiImage}}";
    name = back;
    orderInSides =     (
        "0xd000000000080012 <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/FrameOrderInSide/p2>",
        "0xd000000000040012 <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/FrameOrderInSide/p1>"
    );
})]
frameOrdersInSide.count:2
currentSideIndex: 1
currentSide: <FlashTags.Side: 0x6000002894c0> (entity: Side; id: 0xd00000000008000e <x-coredata://AABA51C1-C3ED-4701-A7DD-BE1CB7B66995/Side/p2> ; data: {
    frames = "<relationship fault: 0x600000029b00 'frames'>";
    orderInFlashcard = 1;
})
framesAvailable:[]
framesAvailable.count:0
PREPARING NEW SIDE'S FRAMES
frameOrdersInSide:[:]
frameOrdersInSide.count:0
```

Comment: Have you tried looking directly at the database using a tool like [Core Data Editor](https://github.com/ChristianKienle/Core-Data-Editor)? Actually being able to see the data has gotten me through many strange issues like this. It seems like maybe the relationship is never making it into the database, but something is setting it up outside of the database as part of the initial loading process, which is something you would see right away if you were looking at the data in the Core Data Editor.

Comment: So I downloaded and installed Core Data Editor, but it seems that certain fields aren't populated in it correctly. I'm not able to see most of the relationships I have that are one to many (most without inverse, but one without an inverse IS showing so..) These are relationships whose values ARE correctly pulled, so I couldn't use it to figure out the issue, but thanks for mentioning it I'm sure it'll be useful in the future.

Comment: I realized that my relationship to frames on a side, Side.frames, because of core data is  an NSSet (No Duplicates), so that screwed with the behavior of adding the same frame to a side multiple times. My join entity FrameOrderInSide which originally had an index and a reference to Side and then my Frame entity had an NSSet of FrameOrdersInSides made it unnecessarily complex, so I reworked my core data design so I don't run into the NSSet issue by putting Frame on FrameOrdersInSide and putting a 1 to many relationship to FrameOrdersInSide on Side. That made the actual loading code much simpler

Answer (score 0):

Here's the updated flashcard loading code after changing my core data design:

```
var sides:[Side] = (flashcard!.cardType!.sides!.allObjects as! [Side])
        sides.sort(by:{$0.orderInFlashcard<$1.orderInFlashcard}) //sides sorted by orderInFlashcard
        currentSideIndex = 0

        for sideIndex in 0..<sides.count{
            let side:Side = sides[sideIndex]
            let framesOrderInSide:[FrameOrderInSide] = (side.frameOrders!.allObjects as! [FrameOrderInSide]).sorted(by:{$0.index<$1.index})
            framesForSides.append(framesOrderInSide.map({$0.frame}))
        }
```